# Advanced pattern matching in proguard to keep multiple packages

Tags: java, proguard

In order to configure proguard to keep all classes from a single package, say `org.myorg.special`, the following notation works:

```
-keep class !org.myorg.special { *; }
```

I would like to configure proguard to keep all classes except when they are from either of **two** packages, say `org.myorg.special` and `org.myorg.another`.

I have tried for instance

```
-keep class !(org.myorg.special,org.myorg.another) { *; }
```

but the above syntax is not supported by proguard.
What is the correct syntax?

Comment: (There is no `except` in the introduction of the first pattern, but it contains a `!`: Please check.)

Answer (score 0):

```
-keep class ![org.myorg.special,org.myorg.another],org.** { *; }
```

Comment: `org.myorg.**` matches both - while the readability suffers with complex patterns.

Comment: thanks, you are right, in reality my example is of course different. I will edit the answer now.